# подсвечивание активной кнопки winforms C#

Tags: c#, winforms

У меня на форме установлены кнопки. Как сделать так что бы при активации кнопки она меняла цвет а при активации другой кнопки возвращался прежний цвет?

Comment: [Focus Events](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/order-of-events-in-windows-forms?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#focus-and-validation-events)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я могу предожить немного более короткую запись идеи из предыдущего ответа:

```
    namespace WindowsFormsApp1 {
        public partial class Form1 : Form {
            public Form1() {
                InitializeComponent();
                var defaultBackColor = button1.BackColor;
                button1.GotFocus += (sender, args) => { button1.BackColor = Color.Red; };
                button1.LostFocus += (sender, args) => { button1.BackColor = defaultBackColor; };
                button2.GotFocus += (sender, args) => { button2.BackColor = Color.Red; };
                button2.LostFocus += (sender, args) => { button2.BackColor = defaultBackColor; };
            }
        }
    }
```

Но, в отличие от предыдущего ответа, я под "активацией" кнопки понимал не нажатие на неё, а то, что кнопка "выбрана", то есть просто игрался с сообытиями `GotFocus` - `LostFocus`

Comment: `foreach(var button in new[] { button1, button2 }) { ... }` :) DRY. Либо вообще прописать 2 делегата `EventHandler` и юзать `sender`

Answer (score 0):

Сначала создаем обработчики события для кнопок, затем создаем поле `_defaultBackColor` этот цвет будет по умолчанию. Поле `_onClickBackColor` будет отвечать за цвет, который появится после нажатия кнопки. Если вы не хотите использовать RGB, то можете выбрать встроенные цвета (к примеру  `Color.AliceBlue` или `Color.Yellow`). Код будет выглядеть следующим образом: `_defaultBackColor = Color.Yellow;`

Ну а внутри обработчиков событий меняете цвет кнопки, которую только что нажали на цвет `_onClickBackColor`, а цвет другой кнопки меняете на `_defaultBackColor`

```
private Color _defaultBackColor;
private Color _onClickBackColor;
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
            
    //Тут задаете цвет, который будет по умолчанию
    _defaultBackColor = Color.FromArgb(175, 175, 175);
    _onClickBackColor = Color.FromArgb(111, 111, 111);

    button1.BackColor = _defaultBackColor;
    button2.BackColor = _defaultBackColor;
}
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Устанавливаете нужный вам цвет в RGB у первой кнопки
    button1.BackColor = _onClickBackColor;

    //Задаем цвет обратно
    button2.BackColor = _defaultBackColor;
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Устанавливаете нужный вам цвет в RGB у второй кнопкиы
    button2.BackColor = _onClickBackColor;

    //Задаем цвет обратно
    button1.BackColor = _defaultBackColor;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное! решил вопрос еще боле простым способом.

Comment: b1.BackColor = Color.DarkOrange;
                b2.BackColor = Color.DarkOrange;
                b3.BackColor = Color.DarkOrange;
                b4.BackColor = Color.DarkOrange;
                b5.BackColor = Color.DarkOrange;
                b6.BackColor = Color.DarkOrange;
                b1.BackColor = Color.Gold;

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста =)